# Groovy's @TypeChecked or @Builder + IntelliJ IDEA = false error complains. Is it a bug?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, typechecking

Groovy 2.3.2 and IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4

Consider following examples:

1.

```
@TypeChecked
class ImmutabilityUtils {

    static List<Map<String, String>> asImmutable(List<Map<String, String>> relatedFeed) {
        relatedFeed*.asImmutable().asImmutable()
    }
}
```

In the above examples line `relatedFeed*.asImmutable().asImmutable()` is underlined with red under the first `asImmutable()` call with message:

*Category method 'asImmutable' cannot be aplied to java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>*

Strange thing to notice - when previously I was doing the exact same operation inline while passing the result as constructor argument IDE wasn't complaining. Something like:

`new FeedProcessor(relatedFeed*.asImmutable().asImmutable())`

where constuctor definition looks like:

`FeedProcessor(List<Map<String, String>> relatedFeed)`

...is not a case for IDE to complain.

[image: Screen shot illustrating issue 1. and 2.]

2.

```
@TypeChecked
class ImmutabilityUtils {

    static Map<String, Map<String, String>> asImmutable(Map<String, Map<String, String>> lookupFeed) {
        lookupFeed.collectEntries { [it.key, it.value.asImmutable()] }.asImmutable()
    }
}
```

To makes things shorter, here we have the exact same situation like in the 1st example. The only difference is that `asImmutable()` method call which is being underlined is the one at the end of the line (after closure's curly bracket close). The IDE's message is

*Category method 'asImmutable' cannot be aplied to java.util.Map<?,?>*

Similar as the 1st example there was no complains when executed inline as constructor argument.

3.

```
@Builder(buildMethodName='build', builderMethodName='builder', prefix='with')
class Whatever { ... }
```

Here the `@Builder` annotation itself is being underlined with message

*Missed attributes: forClass, builderClassName*

Which is wrong as for example *forClass* and *builderMethodName* can't be used at the same time.

[image: Screen shot illustrating issue 3.]

Any red underline in IntelliJ means that code won't even compile. It compiles and works as expected though - both compiled by IDE itself and with Gradle outside of IDE.

Why IntelliJ is complaining about something which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

A red underline does *not* necessarily mean that the code won't compile. It means that IntelliJ's own code analysis *thinks* that there is an error, but it isn't always right - especially for languages other than Java. IntelliJ's Groovy support is good but not perfect, it may not yet be as good for the new `@TypeChecked` mode, and it may not have specific knowledge about lesser/recent AST transforms such as `@Builder` at all (in which case it won't understand them).

The right action in such a case is to file an issue in IntelliJ's [bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) - not only in your own interest, but in the interest of the whole Groovy community.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't mean that the code won't compile as it compiles fine. I just wanted to confirm if in my case something is wrong with my environment or - as you stated - lack of IDE support for recent features or maybe there is some inconsistency in the Groovy itself between @TypeChecked and asImmutable / collect methods contract. I'll issues bug with IntelliJ's tracker then, thanks.

Comment: OK, so for @Builder support the issues was already raised http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125224, I did upvote.

Comment: I reported the 1st issue as well: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128454